# How to stop the execution of test cases fails in Java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, assert

I have a scenario where I need to stop the execution once it reaches one of the condition in else part.
Below is my code.Once the condition reaches else,i want to stop the execution.How do I use assert condition for this?

```
So once I reach last condition ,that is if any employee reaches Exception,I want to stop the execution

If a condition reaches,HR department,variable counter will be incremented by 1 and if it reaches Finance department ,variable i will be decremented by 1

for (int i=0;i<EmployeeID.size();i++) { 
//while(i++<=EmployeeID.size()) {
    if(counter==EmployeeID.size())break;
    stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from Employee where EmployeeID=?");                   
    stmt.setInt(1,EmployeeID.get(i));
    //System.out.println(EmployeeID.get(i));                
    rs3= stmt.executeQuery();
//  while(counter!=EmployeeID.size()) {
        while(rs3.next()) {     
        getCurrentQueueID= rs3.getString("CurrentQueueID");
        if(getCurrentQueueID.equals("1")) {
        log.info(+EmployeeID.get(i) + " is in HR Department");
        counter++;
        //System.out.println("Count is"+counter);
        }

        else if(getCurrentQueueID.equals("7")) {
        log.info(+EmployeeID.get(i) + " is in Finance Department");
        --i;
        System.out.println("Value of i is" +i);
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        }

        else if(getCurrentQueueID.equals("3")) {
            log.info(+EmployeeID.get(i) + " is in Exception");
        }
}   //End of While rs loop
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop test so that it is not considered failed then just use `return;` statement.

If you need to stop test as failed then you either:

- Throw an exception if you do not use any test framework
- OR use `assert false;` statement if you do not use any test framework
- OR use `org.junit.Assert.fail();` if you use JUnit
- OR use `org.testng.Assert.fail()` if you use TestNG